# Log4j properties ignored

Tags: java, log4j

I have standard Maven project in Eclipse. My log4j.properties file is in the resource folder as can be seen from below image. I have a commons-logging.properties file as well to direct any dependencies that might use that to the log4j configuration file.

[image: log4j.properties file in project]

This is the depencies in the gradle.build file:

```
plugins {
  id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '2.0.4'
  id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'net.sourceforge.tess4j', name: 'tess4j', version: '4.2.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.pdfbox', name: 'pdfbox', version: '2.0.11'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.11.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.11.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is the log4j.properties file content:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

As the log4j.properties file did not seem to be picked up automatically I have tried to force load it in the main method:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainScreenApplication.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(MainScreenApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties"));
    System.out.println(props);
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
    logger.debug("Starting");
    // Ensure configuration is loaded and stuff copied to user PC
    ConfigurationManager.getInstance().getConfiguration();
    launch(args);
}
```

Starting the application produces this output:

```
{log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout, log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out, log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout, log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n, log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender}
16:10:10.680 [main] DEBUG com.damco.documenthandler.ui.MainScreenApplication - Starting
```

Clearly the log4j.properties are loaded into the property object, i.e. the date and time format is not even adhered to and it prints debug message even thoug configuration is set to ERROR.

- Why on earth is the logger not following the log4j configuration?

I have been battling with this for way too long :) One of the reasons I want to get this working is that I am using PDFBox and want it to also follow the log4j configuration as it produces quite some debug output in its finalizer methods.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share your commons-logging properties file and try and comment that file and then run your main class.

Comment: It may be useful if you share the pom.xml too. Just to replicate your problem exactly as you have it.

Comment: @PoojaAggarwal - The content of the log4j.properties file is listed in the questions itself. Its the first "code" sectionin gray.

Comment: @Joss I have added the build.gradle content to show dependencies. I do not have a pom.xml in my project.

Comment: Do you run your project from Eclipse or make a jar then run it?

Comment: @EugenCovaci yes I do

Comment: Let's make this test: run the generated jar from console, see if the logging is OK.

Comment: @EugenCovaci Interestingly after you mention that I tried to run the JAR file for my app and it follows the log4j configuration! (Except for that *damn* PDFBox depency which keeps spitting out DEBUG messages)

Comment: It looks like an Eclipse issue. Can you tell me what you have in Properties->Java Build Path->Source?

Comment: I have these three:
src/main/java
src/main/resources
src/test/java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184308/discussion-between-eugen-covaci-and-ben).

Answer (score 0):

**static** might be also an issue an **rootlogger** is unknown.
Try using

```
logger=Logger.getLogger(MainScreenApplication.class);
```

after you do

```
 PropertyConfigurator.configure(props)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried it but it didnt fix it. I think it is very strange.

Answer (score -1):

In `log4j` all the loggers inherit from a parent, and by default the `rootLogger` is the parent of all other loggers and the appender defined for the `rootLogger` also applies to all the child loggers.

Log levels such as `ERROR`, `DEBUG`, `FATAL` etc. follows a hierarchy which means when an appender is set to a level, it will also log all other levels that are lower than the set level. The hierarchy goes like this: `FATAL > ERROR > WARN > INFO > DEBUG > TRACE > ALL`. So when you set a level to `ERROR` all other levels below it `WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, ALL` will also log when you ask it to in your code.

Why on earth is the logger not following the log4j configuration? It is following your configuration precisely. This line `log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout` in the properties file is setting the rootLogger to be of level `ERROR`, and by default your logger in `MainScreenApplication.java` inherits from the `rootLogger`, as you havent defined any loggers for this particular class in your `log4j.properties` file.

If you want a class/package to have their own logger, you need to define it. For your situation:

```
log4j.logger.com.package.to.MainScreenApplication= DEBUG, customAppender
log4j.additivity.com.package.to.MainScreenApplicationt = false #this line is very important as it stops the inheritance from a parent

log4j.appender.customAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.customAppender.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.customAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.customAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But if you look at the output from the console you can see that the log message is not even following the specified data format. Therefore another log configuration must be loaded somewhere that I am not in control of.

As I understand it setting the rootLogger to e.g. OFF should turn off all the logging. But it doesn't. It just keeps printing all my log messages and PDFBox DEBUG messages.

If I build a JAR, the log4j.properties is being honored (except for PDFBox messages!)